# Bootstrap's grid layout not positioning image to the right of text. I have tried `img-fluid` but to no use

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <p class="hcheadingtext">HAPPY CLIENTS</p>
    <h3 class="hcheading">Lost 13kg in 105 days</h3>

<p class="headingtext2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse. p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">


<img class="client img-fluid" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTiT9pitRgeYv8jiKbyE7UBeVAVCOxM2GXQwg&usqp=CAU">
</div>
```

the css is

```
.hcheadingtext {
  padding-top: 20%;
  color: #d95a34;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hcheading {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}
```

I have tried using `img-fluid` but it is not helping. Also when it runs on chrome, there seems to be a padding on the left that is unexplainable by my code. I dont know why the grid layout is not working. I'm a beginner in html, css.

Comment: Checkout official docs. there is no .container and .row in your markup. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

Comment: I forgot to copy that here but even after I use .container and .row, the image and text dont align.